# How to change the row background of list, when i click the row

Tags: react-admin

I am using react-admin to work for my program.
when I use the  ,I do not know how to set the backgroundColor of row when i click it.

```
const rowStyle = record => ({
  backgroundColor:
    record.id === window.location.pathname.split('/')[2] ? '#e0e0e0' : '',
});
    <List
      {...props}
      bulkActions={false}
      actions={<ListActions />}
      exporter={exporter}
      pagination={<Pagination />}
      filters={<SaleInventoryFilter />}
    >
      <Datagrid rowClick="show" rowStyle={rowStyle}>
        <TextField source="item.code" label="Item code" />
        <TextEllipsisField
          source="item.name"
          label="Item name"
          cellClassName={classes.name}
        />
        <TextField source="stockLocation.name" label="Stock location" />
        <TextField source="batch" />
        <TextField source="leadTime" label="Lead time (days)" />
        <TextField source="onHandQty" label="On hand" />
        <TextField source="availableQty" label="Available" />
        <TextField source="reservedQty" label="Reserved" />
        <DateField
          source="updatedAt"
          label={`Updated At (${getOffsetByTimezone()})`}
        />
        <OperationButton />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
```

Above is my work, but it works always have delay.
It need to wait re-render of component.
I expect when I click the row the row  backgroundColor will change to red immediately whether the component have re-render.